# read from file in c#

Tags: c#, file

The code

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)
fs.ReadByte()
```

will read a byte from the file, what should I do to read 2 bytes at a time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allocate a 2-byte array and pass that as argument to the [FileStream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) function.

```
byte[] twoBytes = new byte[2];
int bytesRead = fs.Read(twoBytes, 0, twoBytes.Length);
```

Comment: Make sure your file is a multiple of 2, or deal with the case where you only read one byte (end of file).

Comment: We can use the return value for that. If it's less than what we requested, we've reached EOF.

Comment: Yup, just thought it was worth mentioning, as he's going from reading one byte at a time which will be fine if not EOF, to reading 2 bytes, which could catch someone out if they're not carefull.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the call up in a loop and read into a datastructure eg. byte[] ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'normal' [read method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx). Use the parameters to define the number of bytes you want to read.